# how i can start jar file in anther computer

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans-8

hi I created a password program  by using Netbeans and javadb as database  . the jar file is work fine in my computer but when I try to start jar in anther system it not work and i get through exception that say i can not connect the data  .
here is my code that i used to connect

```
try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Pref.this, ex.getMessage());
        }
  try {
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PROCAT";
    String uName = "root";
    String uPass = "root";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass);
    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
    String SQL = "select * from PASS1";

    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

}
catch (SQLException err) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "can not connect to database");
}
```

Comment: Do you have DB in your another computer?

Comment: Attempting to connect to `localhost` will fail if the other system you are running the `.jar` file from does not have a local instance of that server running.

Comment: thank for replying i install only jdk in other system how i can get server running in another computer because in my computer i start server from inside netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you got two computers called comp_server and comp_client.
Start the database on comp_server with batch-commands like this:

> set port=1527
>   set jvm=path_to_java.exe
>   set cp=path_to_db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\lib*
>   "%jvm%" -cp "%cp%" org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -p %port%

A console is showing you that the database is running and waiting on connections on port 1527.

Now start the client-application on comp_client and connect to 
*jdbc:derby://**comp_server**:1527/PROCAT*

Comment: thank pro i think that is help put if i went that other computer connect to database Separately with out connect to my computer